# Physical simulation- how to create anti-gravity in objects like hot-air balloons

Tags: physics, mathematics

How do you create objects that "defy" gravity like an hot-air balloon?

Then halfway into animation, how do you make the hot-air balloon drop anti-gravity, as it loses heat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of object?

#### Rigid body

An individual **rigid body** cannot be made anti-gravity, however you can make the entire scene gravity point *upwards* by changing Z=-9.8 to a **positive** number in the *Scene* Gravity settings:

[image]

"Gravity" is a property that can be [keyframed](https://docs.blender.org/manual/nb/dev/animation/keyframes/index.html), *i.e.* you can make it change at a given frame.

#### Cloth or soft body

For **cloths and soft bodies** you can choose *what* Gravity each object is feeling. There is a *"Field Weight"* panel in the Physics settings. There you can change *Gravity* to a **negative** number (assuming that you **don't change** the Gravity scene settings!). The slider won't allow you to do that, but you can just type something like `-0.5`.

[image]

Again, this can be keyframed.

### Instead of keyframing

To reverse gravity at a given *location* rather than *time*, you can add a Wind force field (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> *> Force Field > Wind*), make it point downwards, and changing its falloff type to *Tube* and falloff *Power* to something between 1 and 2.

[image]

Here is a scene with a **Soft Body** hot air balloon, with its ***Gravity* Field Weight** set to `-0.3` (Scene *Gravity* is untouched), and with a **Wind Force Field** at a given altitude (also a *Turbolence* Force Field for more wiggling):

[image]

Here's the blend if you want to look at how it's done

[image]

Comment: Your answers have given me new ideas for winds against objects. Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting some ideas for using hot & cold airs against objects, but I am thinking hard and not getting there yet. I'd like to use semi-transparent colours for airs so to observe movements of airs against objects: red for hot air and blue for cold air. This is my question and there is a bounty of 50 (two days left). https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119273/how-to-simulate-blustery-hot-air-cold-air-in-blender/125181#125181